# Using semaphore to control number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

How can I make use of Semaphore class in order to control number of threads that have an access to an object?

Comment: This might not be the best approach.  What problem do you need to solve?

Comment: @Thorbjorn I have to provide access to an object for two threads at a time (only two) and I have to use semaphore and reentrant lock.

Comment: Personally I would submit a suitable runnable to a limited executor, as Semaphores put the logic in the wrong place.  Is this homework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Initialize the Semaphore with the max number of alowed threds,
- reduce the semaphore counter by one if a thread enters the restricted area
- increse the semaphore counter by one if the thred leaves the restricted area

Comment: Thanks, there is one problem though, I have to be able to provide the access to this obj for two threads at any time but those threads must access this object in pairs, so for example first two threads accessed the object and only after those two threads released locks another two threads may start running.

Comment: Why not use Lock, with Semaphore, so that you lock() when the semaphore access count is "2" and unlock() when it returns to 0?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: are the 2 thread that build the pair threads of two kind, or "only" the next 2 threads?

Comment: the threads have to access object in pairs so i.e. if I have four threads 1,2,3,4 then, the access must be (id's of threads are unimportant) 1,2 and 3,4 or 1,3 and 2,4. Only when first pair finishes then next pair may proceed.

Answer (score 2):

One more good thing about using semaphore to control access to resouce is you can resize your semaphore at runtime. For eg you can have some use case where you want to allow more user to access resource based on some business logic and then reduce it again.
Sample code for re sizable semaphore

```
public class ResizeableSemaphore extends Semaphore
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int permit;
    public ResizeableSemaphore(int permit) {
        super(permit);
        this.permit=permit;
    }       

    public synchronized void resizeIfRequired(int newPermit)
    {
        int delta = newPermit - permit;
        if(delta==0) return;
        if(delta > permit) this.release(delta); // this will increase capacity
        if(delta < 0) this.reducePermits(Math.abs(delta));
        this.permit=newPermit;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example of how Semaphore can be used to limit concurrent access to an object:

http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/java-util-concurrent-java-5-semaphore/

The key points being:

- When you construct the Semaphore, you can declare the max concurrency (i.e., number of threads allowed to access concurrently)
- You require each thread to attempt to acquire() the Semaphore; let the Semaphore keep track of concurrent access

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
java.util.concurrent.Semaphore
```

there's an extensive example on how to use it in the javadoc:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939093/semaphore-and-synchronization), and have a look at [this example](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/java-semaphore)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.