# How to control number of threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to control thread count for the below piece of code.

I have written code like the following..

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
 MyThread t = new MyThread(params);
 t.start();
}
```

In the above code , i want to run 3 threads parallally. Once the running threads completed their execution, then again 3 thread should start.

Please give me the piece of code to achieve this?

Comment: Use a `ExecutorService` of some kind...

Comment: A ThreadPoolExecutor to be exact. The [Executors class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) can give you one via `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int size)`

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

Comment: also, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270433/using-semaphore-to-control-number-of-threads